# Django /w gunicorn bottlenecking with tiny cpu and memory usage

Tags: django, linux, nginx, monitoring, gunicorn

I have a django/gunicorn/nginx app on DigitalOcean which starts throwing this error once I get up to 50 req/s.

```
[error] 1608#1608: *584100 connect() to unix:/my/app/gunicorn.sock 
failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to 
upstream, client: 162.158.222.46, server: hbs.hubro.education, 
request: "GET /notification/count/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"http://unix:/my/app/gunicorn.sock:/notification/count/", host: 
"mydomain.com"
```

The cpu usage is really low, in the 10% area, same with memory. I've tried with gunicorn workers equaling the number of cores, twice the cores, and four times the cores, but it seems the bottleneck is somewhere else.

I would be grateful for suggestions on figuring out where the bottleneck is, and if there are any recommended monitoring tools that can give me more data on the issue than the DigitalOcean dashboard, like response times, open file count, workers utilized and whatnot.

Comment: What are the parameters you are running gunicorn with? eg. - max-requests, no. of workers,

Comment: --workers 16 --max-requests 0 --timeout 30 --log-level debug